# Ajuda com menu pós login no JSF no JavaWeb

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Fala galera, beleza ? Estou fazendo um gerenciador de projetos em JavaWeb com Hibernate, TDD, MVC, JSF, Primefaces e mais que não lembro kk, Seguinte, quando eu efetuo o login no meu projeto eu faço o menu aparecer mas quando clico em alguma função, ele some. O teste de autenticação está funcionando ok mas é como se o usuário fechasse e perdesse o login.

Fazendo o Login, aparece:

[image]

Quando clico em qualquer função, ele some:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Menu está feito assim no JSF:

```
<p:submenu label="Usuários" rendered="#{autenticacaoBean.usuarioLogado.funcao != null}">
        <p:menuitem value="Pesquisa e Listagem" outcome="/pages/usuarioPesquisa.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-search" />
        <p:menuitem value="Criar" outcome="/pages/usuarioCadastro.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-disk">
             <f:param name="usuAcao" value="criar" />
        </p:menuitem>
    </p:submenu>
```

A parte de login está assim:

```
<h:form>

    <h:panelGrid columns="2">

    <p:outputLabel value="Email"></p:outputLabel>
    <p:inputText size="30" value="#{autenticacaoBean.usuarioLogado.email}">
    <f:validateBean />
    </p:inputText>

    <p:outputLabel value="Senha"></p:outputLabel>
    <p:password size="30" value="#{autenticacaoBean.usuarioLogado.senha}">
    <f:validateBean />
    </p:password>

    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Entrar" update=":msgGlobal :formLogin:painelMenu"
    actionListener="#{autenticacaoBean.autenticar}"></p:commandButton>

    </h:panelGrid></h:form>
```

A Autenticação Bean tá assim:

```
public class AutenticacaoBean {

private Usuario usuarioLogado;

public Usuario getUsuarioLogado() {
    if(usuarioLogado == null){
        usuarioLogado = new Usuario();
    }
    return usuarioLogado;
}

public void setUsuarioLogado(Usuario usuarioLogado) {
    this.usuarioLogado = usuarioLogado;
}

public void autenticar(){
    try {
        UsuarioDAO usuariodao = new UsuarioDAO();
        usuarioLogado = usuariodao.autenticar(usuarioLogado.getEmail(), DigestUtils.md5Hex(usuarioLogado.getSenha()));

        if(usuarioLogado == null){
            FacesUtil.addMsgErro("Email ou Senha inválidos !");
        } else {
            FacesUtil.addMsgInfo("Usuário Autenticado com sucesso!");
        }

    } catch(RuntimeException ex) {

        FacesUtil.addMsgErro("Erro ao tentar autenticar no sistema.");
    }
}}
```

e no UsuarioDAO está assim:

```
public Usuario autenticar(String email, String senha){
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Usuario usuario = null; 

    try {
        Query consulta = sessao.getNamedQuery("Usuario.autenticar");
        consulta.setString("email", email);
        consulta.setString("senha", senha);
        usuario = (Usuario) consulta.uniqueResult();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        sessao.close();
    }
    return usuario;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutenticacaoBean está com escopo de sessão? tente adicionar a anotação @SessionScoped em AutenticacaoBean.

Comment: Consegui, vc é um deus <3 haha obg mesmo